# Config files change while upgrade sitecore 8.0

Tags: configuration, upgrade

Currently, I have `Sitecore 8.0(update 1)` site and I want it to upgrade it to update 2.

I am following the 8.0 Update-2 Upgrade Guide. In this guide, there is a step of `Apply the configuration file changes described in Sitecore 8.0 rev. 150223 (Update-2) Configuration File Changes document`.

Except following this step(making changes in the config file as per Configuration File Changes document) can we just replace config files with the files which we get from `Config Files for Sitecore XP 8 Update2.zip` folder from 
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/8_0/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_8_update2.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't made any changes to the default config files (which you shouldn't - patch them with your own configs instead), then yes, that should be fine.

Changes to `Web.config` would probably still have to be done manually, as you usually make some changes to that file depending on your solution.

With upgrades I like to just delete the whole `App_Config/Include` folder and add all the configs from a clean Sitecore install. This way you also get rid any files that should be delete, if any, and start clean. Then deploy/publish your solution afterwards.

Comment: Thank you so much.. this really work. One more question regarding upgradation, to upgrade Sitecore 8.0 to 8.1, do we really need to first upgrade sitecore 8.0 with all updates (like from update 1 to 7) and then upgrade it to 8.1 or we can directly upgrade 8.0 to 8.1?

Comment: Yes, according to the upgrade document: `Prerequisites for running this update: Sitecore 8.0 rev.141212 or later`

Answer (score 1):

I would say that totally depends on your solution. Did you ever change anything in one of these current configuration files? The reason why the instructions tell you to modify the local configuration files manually is because of possible changes to them. Sitecore could easily include the web.config or any other configuration file in the automated upgrade process but they definitely don't want to risk to overwrite anything that could harm your solution.